# Add javascript variable in array in json format where variable value changes on mouseClick

Tags: javascript

```
var question="Something?";
var option="a";
var col=[];
```

on click the variable  value changes and values should be pushed in given format. i am new to javascript please me with this. thanks

```
//Onclick the variable value changes
function ClickedMe(question,option)
{
  col.push({"Question":question,"Option":option});
}
```

Output array `col` should be:

```
[{"Question":"Something","Option":"a"},{"Question":"OtherQuestion?","Option":"b"},{"Question":"otherNextQuestion?","Option":"c"}]
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem? What are you clicking? Where are the new questions and options coming from?

Comment: What is the matter with this?

Comment: When you push "Question" and "Option" data to col array, it will automatically be an object array. Your way is good. If u want to store them in json format, use concatination as string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ClickedMe(question, option) {
  let temp = {};
  temp["Question"] = question;
  temp["Option"] = question;
  col.push(temp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
col = [{
    question: 'Something',
    option: 'a'
}]

function ClickMe(quest, opt){
    let newObj = {}
    newObj.question = question
    newObj.option = opt
    col.push(newObj)
}
```

Comment: `col` should be an array onto which objects are pushed when something is clicked.

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood the problem

Comment: value only gets updated but the desired output does not comes. thanks

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer: include an explanation how it solves the problem.